# don't submit form if name field is empty

Tags: javascript, forms, input, submit

I am trying to stop the form from submitting if the name input is empty.
My code works to disable to submit button but once I click again and put a name it remains disable. How can i fix this?

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
<button type="submit">Register</button>

const register = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');

function errorNameInput () {
    let nameUser = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if (nameUser == '') {
        register.disabled = true;
        console.log('please, fill in name');
    } else {
        console.log('submit');
    }
    document.getElementById('name').value = '';
}

register.addEventListener("click", 
    function(){
        errorNameInput();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Why not just use the `required` attribute? Do you really need to support ancient browsers that don't implement it?

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thanks for your answer. I didn't know about 'require' attribute. Interesting. I will research around it. Not sure what you mean when saying they don't implement it?

Comment: It's an HTML5 attribute. IE9 and earlier doesn't implement it.

Comment: I understand. So if the input has required='' but there would be no input value, would the button by default not submit?

Comment: yes. Try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the case where the user has typed something and re-enable the button.

```
function errorNameInput () {
    let nameUser = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if (nameUser == '') {
        register.disabled = true;
        console.log('please, fill in name');
    } else {
        register.disabled = false;
        console.log('submit');
    }
    document.getElementById('name').value = '';
}

register.addEventListener("click", 
    function(){
        errorNameInput();
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
<button type="submit">Register</button>

const register = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');

function errorNameInput () {
    let nameUser = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if (nameUser == '') {
        register.disabled = true;
        console.log('please, fill in name');
    } else {
        register.disabled = false;
        console.log('submit');
    }
    document.getElementById('name').value = '';
}

register.addEventListener("click", 
    function(){
        errorNameInput();
        return false;
    });
```